# How to set the map center attributes from the set of coordinates

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

How to calculate the map center coordinates from the set of below coordinates dynamically. These coordinates am taking from the xml file. Based on the XML coordinates, I want to set the center coordinates.  var triangleCoords = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(51.049042161127545, -3.1417465209960938),
      new google.maps.LatLng(51.00477555656173, -3.1235504150390625),
      new google.maps.LatLng(51.01428024457833, -3.0490493774414062),
      new google.maps.LatLng(51.047962990786715, -3.0806350708007812)
  ];

```
       <html>
        <head>

            <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
            <script>
                function initialize() {


                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.017303, -3.096289);
                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 12,
                        center: myLatLng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                    };

                    var bermudaTriangle;

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
              mapOptions);


                    var triangleCoords = [
              new google.maps.LatLng(51.049042161127545, -3.1417465209960938),
              new google.maps.LatLng(51.00477555656173, -3.1235504150390625),
              new google.maps.LatLng(51.01428024457833, -3.0490493774414062),
              new google.maps.LatLng(51.047962990786715, -3.0806350708007812)
          ];



                    // Construct the polygon
                    bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                        paths: triangleCoords,
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                        fillOpacity: 0.35
                    });


                    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
                    /// To display Marker within the above drawn polygon coordinates 


                    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(51.01428024457833, -3.0490493774414062);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pos,
                        map: map,
                        title: name
                    });

                    var info = "This is a marker for the following co-ordinates:<br />latitude: " + latitude + "<br/>longitude: " + longitude;
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: info
                        });
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                }

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 500px">
            </div>
        </body> 
</html>

    Could you please help me out this.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a method called `map.setBounds`
First you declare a new `LatLngBounds` and then add all the latlngs you have to it.

Like this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(triangleCoords[i]);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

More info on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Comment: Ok thanks. how can we create array like below by putting for loop. var triangleCoords = [ new google.maps.LatLng(51.049042161127545, -3.1417465209960938), new google.maps.LatLng(51.00477555656173, -3.1235504150390625), new google.maps.LatLng(51.01428024457833, -3.0490493774414062), new google.maps.LatLng(51.047962990786715, -3.0806350708007812) ];

Comment: how can we create the array of above traingleCoords dynamically by getting the coordinates from database? Please